# get Sharepoint to default to Save As for Links

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint users are complaining that after logging they are not able to download files. All the files on our site are Microsoft Office files (Excel, Word, PowerPoint). I've recreated this issue:  a user logs in with username and password, the user click the file and instead of prompting for a save location the applicable Microsoft solution loads.  The problem is that the Microsoft solution doesn't load the file, but prompts again for a username and password but the authentication fails, and the file doesn't open.   Right clicking the file and clicking Save As always work.

Telling users to Save As is not desired, and asking them to change browser settings is unacceptable since users may not even have rights to do this at their institution.

Is there a way to set the links in SharePoint to default to "Save As" or is there some other workaround for this problem?

Comment: by the way, for word prompting again: word open with url, but doesn't have the credentials used in IE. That's why it's prompting again. If you trace the dialog box, you will see it's coming from word. To avoid this, you need integrated authentication (or save file on disk first).

Comment: is it just sharepoint foundation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint allows you different cases:

- Download files
- Open files with local Office (Word...)
- Open files as a web pages that looks lile office app through Office Web App (need to be purchased).

You can control behaviour by going to:

- Site actions
- Site Settings
- Site collection features (inside site collection administration group)

### Office Web Apps:

Enables viewing and editing scenarios using the Office Web Apps

### Open Documents in Client Applications by Default:

Configures links to documents so they open in client applications instead of Web applications, by default.

### Example:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I navigated to _Site Actions|Site Settings|Site Collection Features_ and I see 5 Rows of "Features with an Activate/Deactivate button, and it's activation Status.  The 5 feature names are "Bamboo Calendar Plus Web Part," "Dundas Chart Web Part", "Dundas Gauge Web Part", 
"Fields and Content Types for the Windows SharePoint Services Application Templates," and "Three-state workflow" so I don't think your drilldown instructions are quite right.   I also checked "Site features" under "Site Administration" group and I see a longer list about 20 rows" , same format as the former

Comment: Are you just using sharepoint foundation ?

Comment: It's sharepoint 2007 foundation.